# What are the mature CMSs and Blogs built on web2py?

Tags: python, web2py, django-cms

In search of technologies for developing web applications and portals, I recently dabbled into Ruby and Python (from a non-sysadmin point of view .. ie, towards web application development) and immediately fell in love with python.  I have since wanted to only spend time on python based technology for everything (LOL).  I have an immediate need to build a weblog that is also able to function as a corporate website, so I started seeking possible python solutions.

I have researched all the major frameworks and like zope/plone on the enterprise, so I will eventually do a lot in plone.  However, I also need an 'instant' sort of framework that I can roll out very rapidly and use to test out some concepts in a weblog.

Given the amount of excellent python projects out there, that ought to be easy right?  .. Well, WRONG.  That has been real tough, and in the end I could never figure out whether to go with Django or web2py.  Each had excellent advantages.  In the end, I have decided to spare myself the agony and play with both of them initially .. with a hope to quickly discovering the strengths of each of them that are better suited to different projects.

I am going with:

- Django --> Django-cms, other plugins
- web2py --> InstantPress ?, KPax?, other
  plugins?

My my main beef is that there seems to be very little extra information about the web2py based Kpax and Instant press, beyond being listed under 'free appliances' in web2py website.  I have also not seen a well-established alternative to kpax and instantpress.

Question (to those familiar and experienced with web2py):  where can I read more about instantpress or kpax beyond watching 3-year old movies of them?  Or is the idea that I should just get on with it by installing and playing with them?

Thanks in advance for all suggestions and info ..

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you've got the current version, [Instant Press 2.0](https://bitbucket.org/mulonemartin/instantpress/overview). Here's a recent [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vGkR246URRk). Unfortunately, I don't think there's much documentation, though I believe Martin (the creator) is working on that. Note, IP 2.0 is based on [Powerpack 2.0](http://powerpack.tecnodoc.com.ar/powerpack/default/index) (see [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvvWE2rVnR0)).

More basic options are [web2py-cms](https://github.com/lucasdavila/web2py-cms) and [VCMS](http://code.google.com/p/vcms/). You might also consider making use of [plugin_wiki](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/13#plugin_wiki).

Also, a few text editing plugins that may be useful: [web2py_ckeditor](https://bitbucket.org/PhreeStyle/web2py_ckeditor/src), [elRTE WYSIWYG Widget](http://dev.s-cubism.com/plugin_elrte_widget), and [plugin_managed_html](http://dev.s-cubism.com/plugin_managed_html/page1/_managed_html_edit)

KPAX is fairly old -- probably not the best option at this point.

Also, there was a recent discussion among some folks who are interested in joining forces to build a full-featured CMS, so hopefully this will receive some attention right after the upcoming release of web2py 2.0 (very soon).

UPDATE: There are also a few new efforts under development:

- [web2cms](http://w2cms.com/)
- [Movuca](https://github.com/rochacbruno/Movuca) (a social CMS)
- [nanahoshi-cms](http://dev.s-cubism.com/)

Answer (score 2):

I am developing a Social-CMS, By now I don't have too much working besides the core compoments. But the plan is to release the 'alpha' in one month. (my deadline with a client)

https://github.com/rochacbruno/Movuca

The project is inspired in vikuit.com (but will work outside GAE)

While mine social-CMS is not ready, you can go with InstantPress or PowerPack (best options for web2py by now)

Here is a link to the demo. [Movuca Demo Link](http://movu.ca/demo/home/index)

Answer (score 1):

I was in a similar dilemma, but at the end decided to use Django & Django-CMS or FeinCMS.

Although web2py community is nice, there is simply not a single actively developed CMS with some significant number of developers, community etc.

Here is my [post](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.web2py/91915) to web2py mailing list about it:

It might be that it's not difficult to write decent CMS and/or strong blog engine using web2py framework, but I consider there are more important things to do (or write) than writing Yet Another CMS/blog. ;)